# How to clone a data flow in Synapse?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

How to clone a data flow in Synapse?

I see in Azure Data Factory there is a possibility to clone a data flow by going to Data Flows folder and right-click on a data flow. But in Synapse I don't find a way to see the list of the data flows...

Comment: In Synapse Data flows can be created by pipeline in Integration and in the Develop also. Go to Develop-> click on + -> Dataflow. In this pane only you can find the list of Data flows in Synapse.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula, thank you. Please post this as answer and I will mark it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting it as answer for other community members.

In Synapse, you can find the list of Dataflows in the **Develop** pane.

You can create dataflows as well here. Go to **Develop -> + -> Dataflow**.

[image]

**You can create the clone of the Dataflow using the Data flow list here**. It will contain all the dataflows including the dataflows that were created using the Data flow activity in the pipeline.

[image]

The same will reflect in the Dataflow activity of the Pipeline.

[image]